# Can TE and TM modes propagate together in a waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I recently came to understand the TE and TM modes. As it is defined that E=0 for transverse electric and vice-versa. I have a few basic questions in mind which I thought to ask in one thread only.

**Q.1.** While doing a question on waveguides I stumbled upon a question where **both modes mathematically did exist! Can it be possible physically?** How?

**Q.2.** Also can there be more than 1 modes (of either TE/TM) propagating at the same time?

**Q.3.** When is TEM mode possible (specially in rectangular waveguides)?

Comment: Q1. yes, linear superposition; Q2. yes, linear superposition; Q3 when the cross section is not simply connected, eg. coaxial and some such

Comment: Just 1 question, if there are both TE and TM modes then we will have points in space where electric and magnetic fields are NOT perpendicular. wouldn't it violate basic EM theory?

Comment: In general, E and H fields are not necessarily perpendicular; they are so only in the simplest case: open space propagation. Otherwise, they can be pointing relative to each other in any direction.

Comment: Well, that was new for me. I googled it and found many places that helped in understanding this. Thanks :)